# Multiple, Unreplicatable, Different BSODs

Tags: windows-7, bsod

Over the past few days I've been having a series of BSODs with different codes, source drivers, and no real pattern in me being able to replicate them. Picture below.

[image]

The only common "driver" in the dump logs I've seen is ntoskrnl, the Kernal for the OS. I'm really not a Windows expert though, so I have run to the wall of my limited Windows knowledge.

As a note, I ran the default Windows memcheck tool and got no problems. I also ran through the gamut of driver and windows updates. No program or action in particular seems to cause the BSODs. (3 of them have happened while I was asleep)

Here's the BSV output for the latest BSOD from this morning.

```
==================================================
Dump File         : 042314-20389-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 4/23/2014 9:22:29 AM
Bug Check String  : KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000001e
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 2       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 3       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver  : Rt64win7.sys
Caused By Address : Rt64win7.sys+1b620
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+75b90
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\042314-20389-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 4
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 275,608
Dump File Time    : 4/23/2014 9:23:54 AM
==================================================
```

Driver stack for above crash:

```
==================================================
Filename          : hal.dll
Address In Stack  : hal.dll+4a56
From Address      : fffff800`03200000
To Address        : fffff800`03249000
Size              : 0x00049000
Time Stamp        : 0x4ce7c669
Time String       : 11/20/2010 9:00:25 AM
Product Name      : 
File Description  : 
File Version      :  
Company           : 
Full Path         : 
==================================================

==================================================
Filename          : ntoskrnl.exe
Address In Stack  : ntoskrnl.exe+6d5be
From Address      : fffff800`02c1b000
To Address        : fffff800`03200000
Size              : 0x005e5000
Time Stamp        : 0x521ea035
Time String       : 8/28/2013 9:13:25 PM
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
File Version      : 6.1.7601.18247 (win7sp1_gdr.130828-1532)
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
Full Path         : C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
==================================================

==================================================
Filename          : Rt64win7.sys
Address In Stack  : Rt64win7.sys+1b620
From Address      : fffff880`0446a000
To Address        : fffff880`044ef000
Size              : 0x00085000
Time Stamp        : 0x4df1baab
Time String       : 6/10/2011 2:33:15 AM
Product Name      : 
File Description  : 
File Version      : 
Company           : 
Full Path         : 
==================================================
```

Comment: Is it a desktop or a laptop? If it's a desktop then it could be worth trying a different PSU if possible. Also, are you sure there haven't been any problems with the electrical supply in your home, i.e. brownouts/surges? Lastly, it might be worth visually inspecting the motherboard for bulging/leaking capacitors due to the threat of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague particularly if it is an old PC.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience random, different BSoD's relating to different devices is almost always a hardware failure issue.  Usually RAM.

Use a utility like [MemTest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) to test your RAM for a couple *DAYS* and see if any errors pop up.

If you are convinced you RAM is OK, then its time to start swapping hardware to find the culprit.

Since the errors seem to relate to the network adapter (Rt64win7.sys), video (dxgkrnl.sys), file system (NTFS.sys) and the HAL, and assuming all these devices are in-built to your motherboard, I'd start with replacing the motherboard.

- Start with a fresh OS install and newest drivers, still no help?  Hardware.
- Start with RAM.  Test it, and/or replace with known good, see if problem persists.
- If you have a separate video adapter, go to that next.  Replace it with a known good one, see if problem persists.
- Replace motherboard - see if problem persists.

Although I doubt it's the problem, if you have another known-good PSU around, try with that for a while as it's usually really easy to start with PSU replacement as a diagnostics step. ;)

Comment: You can also use Prime95 for a few days to check the processor. You can also try your hard drive in a PC with similar hardware and see if it's stable. You could have a dying hard drive. If you do not have access to a machine with similar hardware, you can try going to your hard drive manufacturers website and download their diagnostic utility, such as Seagate SeaTools.

Comment: It's kinda what I feared. I'll run the men tests over the next few days and see if I get any more BSODs.

Answer (score 0):

Rt64win7.sys is the Realtek Gigabit Network driver. So go to the [Realtek page](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false), download and install the latest driver.

*if you still have crashes, copy the folder **C:\Windows\Minidump** to your desktop, zip the folder and upload the Zip to a cloud service and post a link here so that we can debug this more.*